# AWK Need read one file and serach in another

Tags: awk

I need to read a file and store column 1 and 4, look in a second file using column one and store column 4 of the second file and then do a subtraction with between column 04 of file 01 and column 04 of file 2 . Can you help me? Column 04 is in seconds.

The two files contain the following headers.

```
ID, origin, destination, time
```

I need to get the first ID in file 1, and look in file 2.

For example, take ID 37 from file 1 and look at file 2. When I find it, I need the ID 37 time in the first file to be subtracted from the ID 37 time in file 2

I need the sum of subtraction times.

Wondering if awk is right solution

File 01

```
37 33 44 602.04
39 32 13 602.20
```

File 02

```
37 44 44 602.184852493
39 13 13 602.263704529
```

Output

```
0,2
```

Comment: Hey, can you try to improve your question? I don't understand nothing.

Comment: Please show your expected output given these two sample input files.

Comment: The two files contain the following headers.

ID, origin, destination, time
I need to get the first ID in file 1, and look in file 2.

For example, take ID 37 from file 1 and look at file 2. When I find it, I need the ID 37 time in the first file to be subtracted from the ID 37 time in file 2

Comment: So the header line in each file is comma-separated or comma+space separated but the rest of the lines in each file are just space separated, right? Why would `0,2` be the expected output of subtracting those times in your input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility to consider is splitting the task up into two parts - joining the two files based on that common field, and then doing the math. It avoids having to store part of every line from one file in memory all at once, which is nice if they're big.

The following assumes that a) the files are sorted based on the first column, b) that tabs are used to separate the columns:

```
$ join -j1 -o '1.4 2.4' file1.txt file2.txt | awk '{total+=$2-$1} END {print total}'
0.208557
```

The join command merges the two files on common lines and prints out just the numbers you want to subtract, which are piped to awk to do the actual math.

Edit: Or all in awk:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR { f1[$1]=$4; next }
       $1 in f1 { total += $4 - f1[$1] }
       END { print total }' file1.txt file2.txt
0.208557
```

this stores the ids and times from the first file in an associative array, and then for each line in file 2, if that line's id exists in the array, add the difference of times to the total. Finally, print the total after reading all of the file.

Comment: Hi.That's solve for me 
$ awk 'NR==FNR { f1[$1]=$4; next }
       $1 in f1 { total += $4 - f1[$1] }
       END { print total }' file1.txt file2.txt
0.208557

Answer (score 0):

f1.col4 - f2.col4:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$4;next}{$4=a[$1]?a[$1]-$4:$4}7' f1 f2
```

The output looks like:

```
37 44 44 -0.144852
39 13 13 -0.0637045
41 44 44 -0.0642587
44 13 13 -0.0196296
45 44 44 -0.0145357
47 13 13 -0.014259
```

If you want the f2.col4 - f1.col4, use `$4-a[$1]` in the above code, you get:

```
37 44 44 0.144852
39 13 13 0.0637045
41 44 44 0.0642587
44 13 13 0.0196296
45 44 44 0.0145357
47 13 13 0.0142594
```

Comment: The two files contain the following headers.

ID, origin, destination, time
I need to get the first ID in file 1, and look in file 2.

For example, take ID 37 from file 1 and look at file 2. When I find it, I need the ID 37 time in the first file to be subtracted from the ID 37 time in file 2. The output is just the sum of subtraction

Comment: @DaniloRenatoDeAssis put **all** requirements in question instead of comments. We are answering question to give a hand, not playing computer games,  pass one stage, you added something, then we try passing the new stage...

Comment: Excuse me. I tested the code that you sent and it really does the subtraction of the times. Now I need to do the sum of each subtraction because I need in the end just the sum of the differences.